# Reading csv into dataframe and changing date reformat to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a .csv into a data-frame index by date using the following code:

```
def getCSVData(rawStaticDataPath):

    pattern = 'Overview-trade-pos'+'.csv'

    staticPath = rawStaticDataPath

    with open(staticPath+pattern,'rt') as f:

        csv=pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=0,index_col='date', parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True,names=['date','id','settle_price','settle_price_acc','pos','trade'])        
        print(csv.sort_index().tail())           

    return csv
```

When I tail the file I get the following:

```
                         id  settle_price  
date                                                                       
2017-12-01  BBG.XTKS.7942.S     23.745497        
2017-12-01  BBG.XTKS.3926.S     26.499680       
2017-12-01  BBG.XTKS.9678.S     27.328124        
2017-12-01  BBG.XTKS.8153.S     29.855033        
2017-12-01  BBG.XTKS.2060.S      1.482091
```

Please note that the 31 March 2017 is the latest record date in the .csv. I sorted the .csv by date and below are the final few records:

```
31/03/2017  BBG.XASX.SCP.S  1.70883133  
31/03/2017  BBG.XASX.IFL.S  6.50754463  
31/03/2017  BBG.XASX.MFG.S  18.02732459 
31/03/2017  BBG.XASX.BHP.S  18.340116   
31/03/2017  BBG.XASX.MND.S  9.406557    
31/03/2017  BBG.XASX.VCX.S  2.15897147
```

You can see that in reading the file in the date has been reformatted.

Please note that the dates are beyond the final day in the .csv that I read in.  I think the date has some how been reformatted.

Is there a way that I can change the format of the date index when I read in the  .csv? So I believe the desired output would be:

```
2017-03-09      4740.969526
2017-01-10      2299.551489
2017-02-10   -255026.329808
2017-03-10    -22969.779504
2017-01-11    -11577.120402
2017-01-12    -73150.201727
```

Obviously the order of the records as a result would change.

Comment: that is belong to another question my friend....after the\ change

Comment: I cannot see how `pivot` changes values. I think you may need to rethink *Please note that the 31 March 2017 is the latest record date in the .csv*. Likely later dates are not at the tail end of file. Please sort on index after import and then print tail: `print(csv.sort_index().tail())`. Otherwise please post a few rows of your csv for reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait.  I have edited the question thanks for to your help.  I think the problem stems from reading in the .csv.  Is there a way to reformat the date to the correct transfiguration when reading the data in?

Comment: Again, please post csv for reproducible example so we can see how csv originally looks. This also looks to be day first issues which you set in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). If using Excel, Office defaults to your regional settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We using `strftime`

```
df.index=df.index.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df
Out[300]: 
                        val
01/04/2016  BBG.XTKS.9716.S
01/04/2016  BBG.XTKS.9065.S
01/04/2016  BBG.XTKS.7966.S
01/04/2016  BBG.XTKS.3774.S
01/04/2016  BBG.XTKS.5110.S
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like adding `dayfirst=True` to the read_csv statement did the trick.

```
csv=pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=0,index_col='date', parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True,infer_datetime_format=True,names=['date','id','settle_price','settle_price_acc','pos','trade'])
```